# str_replace two times

Tags: php, cakephp

i have an question.

I have this code

```
<?php
echo str_replace("CDAS","","2/CDAS2/CDAS");
?>
```

that outputs

```
2/2/
```

How do i make it so it only delete "CDAS", like the "match whole word" option in Notepad?

Thanks!

Comment: you only want to replace the **CDAS** and not **CDAS2**?

Comment: no, i want only CDAS, not CDAS2 .... i know that it sounds wierd, but i need to match case  , between / and /, but in some case lke this one CDAS does not have right / .... understand me?

Comment: Wait can you please post the output you want???

Comment: That's not matching case, that's matching a whole word. FTFY.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a regular expression and specify word boundaries:

```
echo preg_replace('/\bCDAS\b/', '', '2/CDAS2/CDAS');
```

[Here's a demo.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/bROMcj)

Comment: And i presume this will work as usual any time, because there are 3 cases '/CDAS/' or 'CDAS/' or '/CDAS' or even 'CDAS'

Comment: This wont match /CDAS in your case cos it wont match /CDAS2

Comment: I dunno if that desired or not

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/zD2OWR => and what would you recommand me, your function, or do an explode by / and then replace all chars ... you know .. ?

Comment: @Empeus: This, 'cause it's shorter :)

Comment: @Empeus Thogh I have noticed the output is: 2/CDAS2//CDAS2/CSD/CDAS5 If that is your desired output with the double slash then yes this answer is best.

Answer (score 0):

Use preg_replace:

```
preg_replace('/CDAS$/', '', "2/CDAS2/CDAS")
```

Something like that.

Of course since I actually have no idea what output you want I cannot be certain this is the right answer.

Comment: And i presume this will work as usual any time, because there are 3 cases '/CDAS/' or 'CDAS/' or '/CDAS' or even 'CDAS'

Comment: @Empeus That is what your function is currently doing, or is it that you want the slashes removed as well?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to fully answer this as what you've described does what it does but I'm guessing you just want the second CDAS item removed?
There are so many ways to skin a cat but perhaps a flexible way would be to use the explode operator to separate the string into components with the '/' symbol and you can then use a while loop or otherwise to replace any matching CDAS items and exit when ever you want.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

and finally recombine the compoents back into a string either with implode or just concatenate the array items.

Comment: :))) i was thinking about this, and already have somewhere else made it that way, but i do want an preg_match, thanks anyway :)